# Is there any way to math min arrays inside array and return a array with the lowest numbers in each array? Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, minimum

Can't seem to wrap my head around this. Tried several solutions with for loops and math.min.

I have an array with arrays with numbers. I need to get the lowest number in each array.

Should look something like this.

```
let array = [[1, 2, 3],[85, 86, 87],[12, 13, 14],[8, 9, 10]]
let output = [[1],[85],[12],[8]]
```

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Sorry. Forgot to put that in. Vanilla JS.

Answer (score 1):

You need to perform this operation on each value of the array => .map

```js
let array = [[1, 2, 3],[85, 86, 87],[12, 13, 14],[8, 9, 10]]


const min = array.map( arr => Math.min(...arr))

// with the desired format: let output = [[1],[85],[12],[8]]
const output = array.map( arr => [Math.min(...arr)])

console.log(min)
console.log(output)
```